# How to transparently mask an object so only the background will be visible?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, mask, css-transforms

### Goal

I would like to create an animated polygon which has parts of it trimmed/cut/masked out so the layer/element/background under it can be seen like this:

[image: Animated polygon with mask showing background]

I created an animation with CSS3 transform. It is a rotating block that looks like its bottom parts are trimmed down while moving. I would like the trimmed part to show what is actually behind/under the rotating block (so its background).

### What I tried

#### Illusion solution

For single color backgrounds, you can just add a shape on top of the animation so it have the illusion of being cut off.

[image: Animated polygon with illusion mask showing single color background]

This obviously doesn't work with pictures:

[image: Animated polygon with illusion mask doesn't work on regular background]

#### Limited solution

If you need to cut off the sides in with a rectangular shape, you can do that by a parent element, but this has obvious limitations. How to do something like this but with an arbitrary polygon? Can you mask in CSS?

```css
body {
  background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAcAAAAHCAYAAADEUlfTAAAAG0lEQVQYV2NMqL7ty4ADMIIkF7SqbsYmP+gkAbAbGgsk/ddhAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
}

.center {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.block {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: transform 1000s 0s linear;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

@keyframes rotating {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.rotate {
  animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class="block rotate"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems like webkit should be able to solve your issue with the -webkit-clip-path css property. http://jsfiddle.net/DpfW7/3/ But unfortunately it removes the object completely when it starts animating.You're still able to use this without the animation.

Comment: background-position is an hint too : http://jsfiddle.net/DpfW7/4/ that brings very close to goal , missing the cover part ...

Answer (score 1):

to trigger z-index, you need to reset position to either: relative, fixed or absolute.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DpfW7/2/)**

```
#mask {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 1;
    position:relative;/* to trigger z-index */
}
```

---

To look like last example, background-position can be efficient.
**[DEMO box cut off from background](http://jsfiddle.net/DpfW7/4/)**

basicly:

```
body {
    background: url('http://takeinsocialmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/cute-kitten-images-photos-0223204033.jpg') fixed;
    background-size:100vw auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#mask {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background:url('http://takeinsocialmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/cute-kitten-images-photos-0223204033.jpg') fixed;
    background-size:100vw auto;
    z-index: 1;
    position:relative;
}
```

Unfortunately, this won't work with `background-size:cover;` since `body` and `#mask` have different size. `background-size` will need to be set via javaScript `onload` and `onresize` for `#mask`.

Comment: You probably misunderstood my question. I don't have a problem with `z-index`. The white box should be on top of the red one. That is the thing that trims down the bottom part. My problem is that the white box should be "transparent" while still trimming down the bottom part of the red box. See [Wezelkrozum"s solution](http://jsfiddle.net/DpfW7/1/), that works but unfortunately only for this specific example.

Comment: @totymedli ah okay, i thought you where dealing with z-index not being triggered properly. For what you look for , usually , background-position:fixed is used . This works fine but , here the background-size cover brings a probleme , body and mask does not have the same size. a compromised could be to use vw units. http://jsfiddle.net/DpfW7/4/ . Else, you will need to use javascript to retrieve height and width to adapt background-size for #mask so it follows size of body background. ...

Comment: I also thought about that solution. But it falls of really easily. Responsive design, dynamic content, just a few things that would mess up really easily.

Comment: @totymedli In my opinion, what you have left is full SVG or bg-position + javascript, have taken a look at clip() css ?. good luck

Comment: Yes, I also thought about animated SVG, however I face the same situation over there. I don't know if I got better options over there. Still your solution is the one that currently the closest for what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to make the white box invisible with bigger z-index than the red box ?

Comment: That way the trimming is gone. Then what is the point of the masking?

Comment: my first thought, too, but then i have read question again... :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/QxG74/2/
Cute kitting version: http://jsfiddle.net/DpfW7/1/

Give the center div a height of 100 pixels and set the overflow to hidden. This way the rotating square get's trimmed at the bottom.

```
#center {
   width: 200px;
   height: 100px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a solution for this specific example. Probably the initial example wasn't the best demonstration. See my edit: "it should work even if the white block is inside the spinning triangle or if it is a circle".